# Cloned SSD works perfect... When original HDD disconnected

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd, mbr

I just resently cloned my hdd with dual boot windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu using macrium to a smaller ssd. If the HDD is disconnected, the SSD will boot like perfectly, fast, with all the programs like it's just an improved version of my old PC. But if the HDD is plugged in I will boot the grub on the SSD and it will take ages to load windows, and after when I check, the old HDD is listed as the C drive. My theory is that the grub/mbr in the new SSD is still calling for the old windows installation because when the HDD is connected it detects that as C: and the SSD installation as F:.

I don't know what to do because of course I want the OSs on the SSD, but keep the 1 TB HDD for storage.

edit: I already edited the boot order, and I pulled the bios boot menu and selected the SSD for booting, that's why I know the new SSD Grub/Mbr is calling the old installation.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it!
I found the solution in another question after googling the right combination of words.
Just open CMD with administrator privileges and type:

> ```
> bcdedit /set {default} device partition=f:
> bcdedit /set {default} osdevice partition=f:
> ```

Where F is the partition of the new windows installation.
Then restart the computer, and you will see that now the new installation starts and is assigned the C: drive letter.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your boot order in the BIOS to prioritize the SSD as your *first* boot option. Do this by entering your BIOS using ESC, Enter, F12, or whatever your system's boot key is. Go to `Boot > Primary Boot Order` and move the SSD to the top. Go to `Boot > Automatic Boot Order` and prioritize the SSD.
Is the SSD already prioritized? I'm unsure at this point. I would just take my word for it instead of trying, but deleting the EFI partition in the HDD would cause the BIOS to look for other EFI partitions, landing on your SSD's bootloader.

Comment: I already edited the boot order, and I pulled the bios boot menu and selected the SSD for booting, that's why I know the new SSD Grub/Mbr is calling the old.

Deleting the EFI partition sounds like a good option, but I would like to try something not destructive first.
I thought about formatting the old disk, but I am trying to avoid deleting anything until I use the new hard drive for a time, and I am sure everything is fine, call me paranoid.